# Reshaping (M, N, O) numpy array to point cloud

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array (2000 x 2000 x 300) composed of 300 binary images (pixel values are either 0 or 1). I would like to get a numpy array of dimension P x 3, where P is however many pixels have value 1.

I want to do this to be able to handle each of the 3 vectors of length P holds the coordinates of our pixels (x, y, z) and be able to plot a point cloud.

Obviously I initially thought about using 3 for loops and appending to lists but that would take extremely long.

Comment: `np.argwhere(array)` will do this.  It produces the X, Y and Z indices in separate arrays, but those are easy to combine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the purpose for `np.argwhere`:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(
 [[[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]],
  [[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,0]],
  [[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,1]]]
)

args  = np.argwhere(array)
print(args)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 2 1]
 [1 0 2]
 [1 2 0]
 [1 2 1]
 [2 0 1]
 [2 2 1]
 [2 2 2]]
```